# how to detect android device contains whether virtual home button or physical home button programatically for all SDK versions(all devices)?

Tags: android

[image]

Some devices contains virtual home buttons as below and some other devices contains physical home buttons like Samsung duos model.my question is how to find which device contains which keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell getevent -lp
```

You will see input devices list with possible events.

Scroll down to key devices which contains `KEY_VOLUMEUP` `KEY_VOLUMEDOWN` or at least `KEY_POWER`.

If you see `KEY_HOMEPAGE` or `KEY_HOME` the button is physical.

If not it's virtual.

Handling in java:

```
try {
        StringBuilder device_folder = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> command_list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        command_list2.add("getevent");
        command_list2.add("-lp");

        ProcessBuilder process_builder2 = new ProcessBuilder().command(command_list2).redirectErrorStream(false);
        Process process = process_builder2.start();
        BufferedReader buffered_reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = buffered_reader2.readLine()) != null) {
            device_folder.append(line + "\n");                    
        }

        if (device_folder.toString().contains("KEY_HOMEPAGE") 
            || device_folder.toString().contains("KEY_HOME")) {
            //physical button
        }

        else {
            //virtual button
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: sorry i am not good at commands, could you please explain me in android porgramatically

Comment: Do you want to check in your java file or do it manually by using adb shell?

Comment: i want to check in java file only

Comment: did you get your solution?

Comment: No i did not get the answer, "device_folder.toString()" is giving null values only..

Comment: if you are gonna use adb, use getevent -lp